# Google Analytics report that shows percent change in browser usage

Tags: google-analytics

I have google analytics set up to monitor websites. I can view the Browser and OS usage for a specific date range. What I am wondering is if google analytics has a way to show how much a specific browser has increased or decreased over a period of time.

For example, the default date range is 1 month. Is there something built into google analytics that would say the usage of IE8 (or any browser) is down 10% compared to the last month (besides doing a manual calculation)?

Comment: No, there is no such built-in functionality. You will have to do it manually !!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a delta on browsers, sessions, transactions and conversion rate for your site - one could get a statistical inference from that.

Answer (score -1):

Top right hand corner shows the date range. Change it as you want and tick the "Compare  to:" box to compare to previous period (e.g. month before), previous year or custom dates and get all the details you are looking for.

Standard part of using GA to be honest.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking. They're asking about how to report on the trend in percentage (of total) for a particular browser. This is subtly different from usage trend. Using IE8 as an example, if an app's overall traffic is increasing, then it's IE8 usage is also probably increasing, but IE8's percentage of total traffic may be going down, so just comparing to the previous month won't often work.

Comment: But GA reports on all this. For example Audience->Technology->Browser & OS and add a separate metric for Browser Version. Then compare results to previous month. You will see absolute values (e.g. IE8 users decreased this month from 1,000 users to 800 users) and also percentage (e.g. IE8 decreased from being 25% of the site traffic to 22%).

Comment: But you can't see a trend. The only way to do this currently is to export the data (or request it with via the API) and plot the trend yourself.